# Browser-Update.org customization

Tags: javascript

I am trying to implement the script from the Browser-Update.org project that checks browser versions and prompt the user to update if they are using an old version. [It can be found here.](https://browser-update.org/)

In their [customization documentation](https://browser-update.org/customize.html) , they allow you to execute javascript when the information bar is shown:

```
onshow: function(infos){},      // callback function after the bar has appeared
```

I cannot figure out where to insert this in their script. I want to run the following javascript when the onshow is fired:

```
document.getElementById('Submit').disabled = true;
```

Here is what I have tried unsuccessfully:

```
<script> 
var $buoop = {c:2};

function $buo_f(){ 
 var e = document.createElement("script"); 
 e.src = "//browser-update.org/update.min.js"; 
 document.body.appendChild(e);

};
try {document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", $buo_f,false)}
catch(e){window.attachEvent("onload", $buo_f)}

onshow: function(infos){
    document.getElementById('Submit').disabled = true;
};

</script>
```

I am a real JavaScript novice and I'm lost on this. Thanks.
-Brian

Comment: Did you try putting your code in the function?

Answer (score 1):

This is one way:

```
onshow: function(infos){
    document.getElementById('Submit').disabled = true;
},      // callback function after the bar has appeared
```

You could also call a function within that.

Here would be the complete  block if you chose to keep it all in there.

```
<script> 
var $buoop = {
    vs: {i:6,f:2,o:9.63,s:2,c:10},  // browser versions to notify
    reminder: 24,                   // atfer how many hours should the message reappear
                                // 0 = show all the time
    reminderClosed: 150             // if the user closes message it reappears after x hours
    onshow: function(infos){
        document.getElementById('Submit').disabled = true;
    },      // callback function after the bar has appeared
    onclick: function(infos){},     // callback function if bar was clicked
    onclose: function(infos){},     //

    l: false,                       // set a language for the message, e.g. "en"
                                // overrides the default detection
    test: false,                    // true = always show the bar (for testing)
    text: "",                       // custom notification html text
                                // Optionally include up to two placeholders "%s" which will be replaced with the browser version and contents of the link tag. Example: "Your browser (%s) is old.  Please <a%s>update</a>"
    text_xx: "",                    // custom notification text for language "xx"
                                // e.g. text_de for german and text_it for italian
    newwindow: true                 // open link in new window/tab
    url: null                       // the url to go to after clicking the notification
};

function $buo_f(){ 
 var e = document.createElement("script"); 
 e.src = "//browser-update.org/update.min.js"; 
 document.body.appendChild(e);

};
try {document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", $buo_f,false)}
catch(e){window.attachEvent("onload", $buo_f)}

</script>
```

Comment: How should that be placed in my actual script? I updated my question with my code example.

Comment: edited my answer. That's how you can completely customize the library. You can more than likely add/remove options as you see fit, but I didn't test it out so I went ahead and threw what their example up there instead of just including the onshow!